# Automatic Upload to Dropbox on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dropbox

I setup the Dropbox uploader script for the Raspberry pi and was able to successfully upload a file to Dropbox, but now I need to setup an auto script to upload the files into a specific destination folder within Dropbox. I recently found a script that would do just that, but my problem with it is that I cant specify a Destination folder within Dropbox. Other users replied on the forum post asking for an input for a destination folder as well but the post has been inactive for months.

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=164166

I researched other stackoverflow posts related to this problem, but they would not work in my circumstance. Both scripts work great but I would like to see if its possible to alter the script to specify a destination folder within dropbox.

syncdir is the local folder for upload.

I need an input for something like "/dropbox/TeamFolder" instead of just uploading the files straight into my Dropbox user directory.

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#The directory to sync
syncdir="/home/pi/Dropbox-Files/"
#Path to the Dropbox-uploaded shell script
uploader = "/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh"

#If 1 then files will be uploaded. Set to 0 for testing
upload = 1
#If 1 then don't check to see if the file already exists just upload it, if 0 don't upload if already exists
overwrite = 0
#If 1 then crawl sub directories for files to upload
recursive = 1
#Delete local file on successfull upload
deleteLocal = 0



#Prints indented output
def print_output(msg, level):
    print((" " * level * 2) + msg)


#Gets a list of files in a dropbox directory
def list_files(path):
    p = Popen([uploader, "list", path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output = p.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")

    fileList = list()
    lines = output.splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(" [F]"):
            line = line[5:]
            line = line[line.index(' ')+1:]
            fileList.append(line)

    return fileList


#Uploads a single file
def upload_file(localPath, remotePath):
    p = Popen([uploader, "upload", localPath, remotePath], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output = p.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip()
    if output.startswith("> Uploading") and output.endswith("DONE"):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


#Uploads files in a directory
def upload_files(path, level):
    fullpath = os.path.join(syncdir,path)
    print_output("Syncing " + fullpath,level)
    if not os.path.exists(fullpath):
        print_output("Path not found: " + path, level)
    else:

        #Get a list of file/dir in the path
        filesAndDirs = os.listdir(fullpath)

        #Group files and directories

        files = list()
        dirs = list()

        for file in filesAndDirs:
            filepath = os.path.join(fullpath,file)
            if os.path.isfile(filepath):
                files.append(file)       
            if os.path.isdir(filepath):
                dirs.append(file)

        print_output(str(len(files)) + " Files, " + str(len(dirs)) + " Directories",level)

        #If the path contains files and we don't want to override get a list of files in dropbox
        if len(files) > 0 and overwrite == 0:
            dfiles = list_files(path)

        #Loop through the files to check to upload
        for f in files:                                 
            print_output("Found File: " + f,level)   
            if upload == 1 and (overwrite == 1 or not f in dfiles):
                fullFilePath = os.path.join(fullpath,f)
                relativeFilePath = os.path.join(path,f)  
                print_output("Uploading File: " + f,level+1)   
                if upload_file(fullFilePath, relativeFilePath) == 1:
                    print_output("Uploaded File: " + f,level + 1)
                    if deleteLocal == 1:
                        print_output("Deleting File: " + f,level + 1)
                        os.remove(fullFilePath)                        
                else:
                    print_output("Error Uploading File: " + f,level + 1)

        #If recursive loop through the directories   
        if recursive == 1:
            for d in dirs:
                print_output("Found Directory: " + d, level)
                relativePath = os.path.join(path,d)
                upload_files(relativePath, level + 1)





#Start
upload_files("",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the dropbox_uploader.sh script you specify the folder to save the file to on the Dropbox account.  However, that is limited to whatever settings you gave the "app" in the Dropbox settings to get your access token.  You can set it to allow reading/writing anyplace in your Dropbox account or only in a specific folder.

Look for "Permission Type" and "App Folder Name" on the Dropbox apps setup page: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else needing an answer to this, you need to change the `remotePath` in the upload function to your remote path.

Before:

```
p = Popen([uploader, "upload", localPath, remotePath], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

After:

```
p = Popen([uploader, "upload", localPath, "MyRemoteDropboxDirectory"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Technically, you should probably integrate this into the code properly using config variables like they do for source directories etc but I was too lazy to do that.

Hope that helps!